# ConcurrentModificationException in Hibernate query.uniqueList

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, weblogic, workmanagers

I am working on a performance issue on a large volume of data.I am trying to use work managers provided by weblogic to distribute the work into several threads.Yet,I am receiving the following exception while trying to fetch a specific record from a table.

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:365)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:384)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.util.IdentityMap.entryArray(IdentityMap.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.util.IdentityMap.concurrentEntries(IdentityMap.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1185)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1261)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:890)
```

Is this because of multi-threading? The hibernate version I am using is 3.6.1. The exception is quite random: sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes putting a debug point in Eclipse does the trick.

*Edit : 
The code snippet which raised the exception :

```
public Dto findRecentRequests()
{
    Dto dto = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback()
    {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException
        {
            Query q = session.createQuery(newQuery);
            q.setMaxResults(1);
            return (Dto) query.uniqueResult();

        }
    });
    return dto;
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code that raises this exception.

Comment: Your sentence `The exception is quite random: sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes putting a debug point in Eclipse does the trick.` indicates that this is probably multithreading problem. Maybe you schould use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of ordinary hash map but without relevant code this is just shooting in the dark

Comment: You **cannot** use multiple threads with a single `Session`. Data loaded in one session **can only be used in a single `Thread`**. Unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider in fact, you can work with the data from the list using several threads (I did it previously using `ExecutorService`). The problem lies in the code that performs the calls.

Comment: OP: that's part of the relevant code. You must also post how are you calling this code using your multi thread strategy.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you can if you eagerly load the data, i.e. if you know what you're doing. Otherwise you cannot.

Comment: @Ziker : The LinkedHashMap is being used internally in Hibernate from uniqueResult() -> list() -> autoFlush()

Comment: Looking at the error, it could well be the case that you are looping over a collection and altering it at the same time. It does not have to be related to threads - review your code very carefully to ensure that you are not altering a collection while looping.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : The query is to select a refernce data and I am no way altering any of its content.There are certain update operations which I perform on some other entities.Does it have any connection to one another ?

Comment: Same problem here. Code is big but I should not modify any entity on this project and I can't find any mistake about it.